# create a multidimensional array in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am creating a multidimensional array in matlab which has three paramter , number , width and height

```
A = randn(number,width,height)
```

My problem is number is dynamic variable which increase when it find objects in the text file. How i am suppose to make the number variable dynamic,

I tried this but it didnt worked

```
A = randn(:,width,height)
```

Comment: First you should find `number`, then you should call `randn`.

Comment: I cant , its like words are hidden in a text file. it can be zero or can be maximum.

Comment: Can you then give a description of your variables and a stepwise explanation of what you are trying to do? This is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Do you need the data to be normally distributed over all the matrix, or you just chose `randn` to create a matrix as if it is `zeros` or `ones`?

Comment: I am creating a empty matrix of dimension 3, and popualting with random number, in future in will fill it with the data coming from a text file. I know the object size (width and height) but dont know how much objects are these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
i = 0;
when (object in text file)
i = i+1;
A(i,:,:) = data;
end
```

data is of size - `width x height`

Comment: or just append `A = []; while A = [A; data] end` here the size is `(number x width, height)` You can later make it 3D matrix using **reshape**....

Answer (score 1):

first count the number and then allocate the matrix accordingly.

```
i = 0;
when (object in text file)
i = i+1;
end

A = randn(i,width,height);
```

Comment: but then i have to run the loop again to get the objects.

Comment: I thought you just needed to count the objects. You can get them during the first loop.