# Multidimensional array stacking in Matlab

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Is there any short way to stack `d` outputs of `ndgrid(x1,..,xd)` into a `d+1`-dimensional array without using workarounds like cycles

```
cgrid=cell(1,d);
[cgrid{:}]=ndgrid(x1, x2, ... , xd);
agrid=zeros([d, size(cgrid{1})]);
for jj=1:d
    agrid(jj,:)=reshape(cgrid{jj},size(agrid(jj,:)));
end
```

or `agrid=reshape(cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) c{:},cgrid)),[d, size(cgrid{1})])`?

It seems to me that even simple operations with multidimensional arrays require lots of low-level commands.

Comment: Check this post. It might be helpful.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770081/create-a-multidimensional-array-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cat` to do this:

```
buffer = cell(1, 3);
[buffer{:}] = ndgrid(1:10, 1:10, 1:10);
stacked = cat(length(buffer + 1), buffer{:});
```

Note that this is not exactly equivalent to the code you posted, since in this version the new index is in the last dimension (so `stacked(:, :, :, i)` is `buffer{i}`). You can use `shiftdim` to shift the dimensions around:

```
shifted = shiftdim(stacked, ndims(stacked) - 1);
```

Then `squeeze(shifted(i, :, :, :))` is equal to `buffer{i}`.

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for.